# Lost all changes to javascript and html files saved locally in Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, data-recovery

Yesterday I was working all day on a set of large files involving a view, a controller and a javascript file. I had made huge refactoring changes and additions to all three. I saved all my changes locally continuously but did not check in or shelve these changes to source control.

Today I opened Visual Studio to find that my controller changes were still there locally but all of my work on the view and javascript files were completely gone..

My view and javascript files have reverted back to how they were before I made changes.

Is anyone able to offer suggestions on how I can possibly find these missing changes?

I did not expect this to happen and will definitely shelve my changes everytime now before leaving work.

Answer (score 0):

So the most reasonable explanation is that my pending changes were all undone to those specific files by accident.

I was deploying from another repository branch shortly after I finished working on those files and while merging change-sets into that branch we encountered errors that we decided ultimately to undo pending changes on.

What I must not have realized is that my changes from the other branch must have come up in the pending changes list and I inadvertently undid all my hard work..

**The only advice I can offer to people who find themselves in this situation is to exclude pending changes from other mapped branches by going to `Pending Changes`, and in `View Options`, under `Included Changes` and `Excluded Changes`,  select `Show Solution Changes` instead of `Show All`**

Ultimately it was my mistake.